# Roots of transcendental equations in physics problem

Tags: physics, transcendental-equations

I have a physics problem where I have to find for which angle and time is the target at distance $r$ and height $0$ hit if initial velocity is $v_0$.
I am aware that this problem is very basic and I also understand the physics behind it and how you solve it, but I am not sure about the mathematical side. So I have a set of equations:$$v_0\cdot \cos(x)\cdot t=r$$ $$v_0 \cdot \sin(x)\cdot t -\frac{gt^2}{2}=0$$ $$0<x<\pi/2$$
I know intuitively that I should have two angles and two times that solve the set of equations, but I am not sure how can one tell, mathematically speaking, that the given system has two solutions. I would normally solve this by factoring out $t$, but than I only get one valid solution. Only after solving $\cos(x)^2+\sin(x)^2=1$, I get both solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second equation $v_0 \cdot sin(x)\cdot t -\dfrac{gt^2}{2}=0$ says that
$$(v_0 \cdot sin(x) - \frac{gt}{2})\cdot t = 0 .$$
Thus either $t = 0$ or $t = \dfrac{2v_0\sin(x)}{g}$. The solution $t = 0$ disqualifies because the first equation would produce $0 = r$. Therefore we must have
$$t = \frac{2v_0\sin(x)}{g} .$$
Inserting in the first equation produces
$$\sin(2x) = 2\cos(x)\sin(x) = \frac{gr}{v_0^2} . $$
Thus a solution $x$ exists if and only if $\dfrac{gr}{v_0^2} \le 1$, i.e $v_0 \ge \sqrt{gr}$. The third inequality says that $0 < 2x < \pi$, thus you get two solutions for $x$ if $v_0 > \sqrt{gr}$ and one solution $x = \pi/4$ if  $v_0 = \sqrt{gr}$. Thus the final result is this:

Your system of three equations has a solution if and only if
$$v_0 \ge \sqrt{gr} .$$
If $v_0 > \sqrt{gr}$ you get two angles $x \in (0,\pi/2)$ determined by 
$$\sin(2x) = \frac{gr}{v_0^2} .$$
The smaller angle $x_s$ has the property $0 < x_s < \pi/4$, the bigger angle $x_b$ has the property $\pi/4 < x_b < \pi/2$ and is related to $x_s$ by $x_b = \pi/2 - x_s$.

If $v_0 = \sqrt{gr}$ you get one angle $x = \pi/4$.

For each possible angle $x$ you get the time
$$t = \frac{2v_0\sin(x)}{g} .$$

**Edited:**

The physical problem is to study a projectile shot at an angle $x \in (0,\pi/2)$ with the initial velocity of $v_0$, with gravity $g$ acting on it, air resistance is neglected. The shooting takes place in a *plane*.

Its trajectory lies an a parabola and has parameterization
$$\phi(t) = (r(t),h(t)) = (v_0 \cdot \cos(x)\cdot t, v_0 \cdot sin(x)\cdot t -\dfrac{gt^2}{2}) \in \mathbb R^2 .$$
Therefore, given $x$ and $v_0$, the projectile hits the ground at the distance $r(t^*)$ where $h(t^*) = 0$ with $t^* > 0$. We get $t^* = \dfrac{2v_0\sin(x)}{g}$ and
$$r(t^*) = \dfrac{v_0^2 \sin(2x)}{g} .$$
Clearly the maximal firing range occurs at an angle of $x = \pi/4$ where $\sin(2x) = 1$. Moreover, given $x$ and $r = r(t^*)$, we see that we must  have
$$v_0 = v_0(r) = \sqrt{\frac{gr}{\sin(2x)}} \ge \sqrt{gr} .$$

Comment: Is there maybe a physical interpretation of condition $v_0 >\sqrt{gr}$?

Comment: @david1201 To answer this question you must give more information about the physical problem.

Comment: It's a projectile shot at an angle x with the initial velocity of $v_0$, with gravity g acting on it, air resistance is negligible. Then we have a target at a distance r from projectiles initial position and we have to find for which t and x is the target hit.

Comment: @david1201 It is obvious that you will need a minimal speed to hit the target because the trajectory of the projectile lies on a parabola determined by $x$ and $v_0$. But to determine this minimal speed requires calculations, and this is what we have done.